# Paypal notify_url if IPN not enabled

Tags: paypal

If my Paypal account does not have the IPN URL enabled, will it still be possible to receive POST data from Paypal if I use the notify_url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`If the IPN is not enabled for the account and I set the notify_url, will I receive anything?`

**Yes**, you will receive IPN.

`notify_url` will keep sending IPN notifications when used.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will currently work on a PayPal account where the "global" IPN URL has *never* been set/enabled or where it is currently set/enabled.  However, if you disable a previously enabled PayPal global IPN URL, any buttons with notify_url will stop working even if they worked before (they actually get queued in the IPN message queue but not sent like they used to).  My conclusion is that the first time you enable the global IPN URL, PayPal initializes the IPN message logger/queue for your account.  From there, there is no way to get back to the original behavior that I can find.  On the bright side, this same logger/queue makes it really easy to inspect and troubleshoot (and even re-send) IPN messages...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean no IPN URL *defined* at PayPal, yes, provided you have IPN enabled.

You can supply the `notify_url` yourself in the per-button form data.

Comment: If the IPN is not enabled for the account and I set the notify_url, will I receive anything?

Comment: I'd be astonished, but you could always try it.

Comment: @EJP notify_url when used in code, will send IPN even when IPN is not enabled in PayPal profile settings.

Comment: @Vimal OK, consider me astonished.